# Issue with useradd command

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I am getting an error while executing adduser command on the ubuntu 22.04 LTS image. It is giving **Unknown option: m error**

```
sudo adduser -m -d /var/lib/jenkins jenkins
Unknown option: m
Option d is ambiguous (debug, disabled-login, disabled-password)
adduser [--home DIR] [--shell SHELL] [--no-create-home] [--uid ID]
[--firstuid ID] [--lastuid ID] [--gecos GECOS] [--ingroup GROUP | --gid ID]
[--disabled-password] [--disabled-login] [--add_extra_groups]
[--encrypt-home] USER
   Add a normal user
```

It used to work fine before. Any idea why it is giving error?

Comment: Replace `adduser` with `useradd`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `adduser` command defaults to creating a user home directory. So you don't have to specify a `-m` option, actually no such option exists, as the `man` page clearly documents. There only is a "opt out" option `--no-create-home` to disable the home directory creation.

Just as @Cyrus points out there is the `useradd` command that offers an alternative to `adduser`. That one indeed offers the `-m` option to create a user home directory.

You claim that `sudo adduser -m -d [...]` worked fine before. Maybe you had a symlink mapping `adduser` onto `useradd`? Or an alias definition going the same?